# Does every quasisimple finite group have a faithful complex irrep?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, simple-groups

Every simple finite group has a faithful complex irrep. Indeed any nontrivial irrep of a simple finite group is faithful. That leads me to ask:

**Does every quasisimple group have a faithful complex irrep?**

Note: I am aware that not all finite groups have a faithful complex irrep. For example, any noncyclic abelian group (e.g. $ C_2 \times C_2 $) has no faithful complex irreps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. A quasisimple group has a faithful irreducible representation if and only if the centre is cyclic. Since there are simple groups with non-cyclic Schur multiplier (e.g., $PSL_3(4)$, which has Schur multiplier $4\times 4\times 3$), there are no faithful irreducible representations of $4^2.PSL_3(4)$.

Edit: I should say, morally the answer is 'yes', because finite simple groups have cyclic Schur multiplier. The problem is for some small groups, for example $PSL_3(4)$, $Sz(8)$, $PSU_4(3)$, this isn't true, and also, as one comment just reminded me, the orthogonal groups $\Omega_{4n}^+(q)$ for $q$ odd and $n\geq 2$. But there are only finitely many such examples, apart from the orthogonal groups.

Edit 2: Just to clarify, the situation for **quasisimple** groups is that they have faithful, irreducible representations if and only if they have a cyclic centre. This is not difficult to see by inducing a faithful linear character for the centre. In general, this is not sufficient. [This MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57129/which-finite-groups-have-faithful-complex-irreducible-representations) gives information about the general case.

Comment: What does $4^2.PSL_3(4)$ mean?

Comment: It is a group with centre $C_4\times C_4$ and quotient group $PSL_3(4)$. It is unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: @verret The implied hypothesis is that the central extension of $ PSL_3(4) $ by $ C_4 \times C_4 $ is quasisimple. In particular then it must be perfect. A direct product $ C_4 \times C_4  \times PSL_3(4) $ is not perfect since the commutator subgroup is $ PSL_3(4) $ which is a proper subgroup. Of course, as you point out, there is not a unique central extension of $ PSL_3(4) $, since the direct product $ C_4 \times C_4  \times PSL_3(4) $ is an alternative non-perfect central extension. The claim is for a unique *perfect* central extension (i.e. a central extension which is quasisimple).

Comment: I assume he was characterisiting the group in the class of all groups, rather than quasisimple groups. I deleted my comment.

Comment: Many Chevalley groups of type D4 have Schur multiplier C2*C2 so the claim in the first edit is false.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Thanks for noticing that. I've added the orthogonal groups.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline You mean $C2 \times C2$, not $C2*C2$, which is an infinite group.