# Weyl group of $F_4$ and its degree $4$ representations

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

The Weyl group of $ F_4 $
$$
W(F_4) 
$$
is a solvable group of order 1152. $ W(F_4) $ can be realized as the symmetries of the 24-cell, which is a certain convex regular 4-polytope. Thus $ W(F_4) $ is a subgroup of $ O_4(\mathbb{R}) $.

Are there other degree 4 representations of $ W(F_4) $? For example is there a $ W(F_4) $ subgroup of $ SU_4 $? Is there a $ W(F_4) $ subgroup of $ PU_4 $ (i.e. a faithful projective degree 4 representation of $ W(F_4) $)?

Comment: There are five characters of degree $4$. Four are the reflection representation and its images under the outer automorphism group, and one is not faithful. All are of + type.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven thanks that's really helpful! What does "+ type" mean?

Comment: + type means that it stabilizes a symmetric bilinear form, i.e., has Frobenius-Schur indicator +1.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Ok I went and learned some stuff and found that $ W(F_4) $ is SmallGroup(1152,157478) and I've checked probably all the same stuff you did in GAP and learned what Frobenius-Schur indicator means etc I get now that the existence of the 4 faithful + type rep of $ W(F_4) $ of degree 4 mean its a subgroup of $ O_4(\mathbb{R}) $.  The final thing I'm wondering is if there is a $ W(F_4) $ subgroup of $ SU_4 $? It seems to me that since its all + type then subgroup of $ SU_4 $ is really subgroup of $ SO_4 $

Comment: and subgroup of $ SO_4 $ of order $ 1152 $ corresponds to the the lift through the double cover $ SO_4 \to SO_3 \times SO_3 $ of some subgroup $ H_1 \times H_2 $ of $  SO_3 \times SO_3 $ of order $ 576 $. But since this 4d rep of $ W(F_4) $ is irreducible seems that $ H_1 $ and $ H_2 $ should be irreducible subgroups of $ SO_3 $. So only options are $ A_4,S_4,S_5 $. By order considerations only $ H_1=H_2=S_4 $ works but then one can check by GAP that $ W(F_4)/Z(W(F_4)) $ is not isomorphic to  $ S_4 \times S_4 $. So $ W(F_4) $ is not a subgroup of $ SO_4 $ or $ SU_4 $. Does that sound right?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven sorry what I said was probably unclear. My bad! $ W(F_4) $ is certainly a subgroup of $ O_4(\mathbb{R}) $. But I am claiming that $ W(F_4) $ is not a subgroup of $ SO_4(\mathbb{R}) $.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-cell confirms that "The full symmetry group of the 24-cell is the Weyl group of F4, which is generated by reflections through the hyperplanes orthogonal to the F4 roots. This is a solvable group of order 1152. The rotational symmetry group of the 24-cell is of order 576." Also see https://www.abstract-polytopes.com/atlas/1152/157478/1.html for some standardized information including GAP id

Comment: Reflections have determinant $-1$.

Comment: Haha yes I know that! Unfortunately I don't have an explicit 4d representation on hand with matrices that I can just take the determinant of.  Do you know any explicit generators? Or do you know how to figure out if half the elements have det=-1 in this case just based on character tables?

Comment: On a more general note, I really appreciate your time and all the things I've learned from you especially your wonderful answer to my question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414315/finite-simple-groups-and-operatornamesu-n. That said, your comment above "Well, you cannot have that $G=W(F_4) $ both is and isn't a subgroup of $O_4(\mathbb{R}) $, so you have done something wrong." is uninformative, condescending and even incorrect since I never claimed  $ W(F_4)  \not \subseteq O_4(\mathbb{R}) $. We all have bad days, but MSE should be kind respectful and accurate!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4377934/does-every-quasisimple-finite-group-have-a-faithful-complex-irrep is another example of a really great answer you gave to one of my questions, just want to express my gratitude again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that while $ W(F_4) $ is a subgroup of $ O_4(\mathbb{R}) $ it is not a subgroup of $ SO_4(\mathbb{R}) $ or $ SU_4 $ or $ PU_4 $. That is, it has no faithful determinant $ 1 $, degree $ 4 $ irreps and also it has no degree $ 4 
 $ projective irreps.

The one primitive subgroup of $ SU_4 $ that has the right order to be a central extension of $ W(F_4) $ corresponding to a projective representation is group 21 from https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905212 but one can directly verify, using GAP say, that this group is not a central extension of $ W(F_4) $.

It is interesting to note that since $ W(F_4) \subseteq O_4(\mathbb{R}) \subset SO_6(\mathbb{R}) $ then we can lift $ W(F_4) $ through the double cover $ SU_4 \to SO_6(\mathbb{R}) $ to get a subgroup of $ SU_4 $ of order $ 2(1152)=4(576) $. This corresponds to a degree 4 projective irrep of the direct product $ S_4 \times S_4 $ (recall that $ W(F_4) $ is a central extension by cyclic 2 of $ S_4 \times S_4 $). This does not give an actual degree 4 projective irrep of $ W(F_4) $ but its basically the closest we can get.

As stated in the comments, $ W(F_4) $ does have four different faithful 4d irreps mapping into $ O_4(\mathbb{R}) $ (i.e. irreps of $ + $ type, meaning Frobenius-Schur indicator $ +1 $). These all correspond to nonconjugate $ W(F_4) $ subgroups of $ O_4(\mathbb{R}) $. Don't really know anything else about them though.